# Is resilience4j required when using Project Reactor?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-netflix, resilience4j

Project Reactor has features for timeout, retry, fallback functions wrt exceptions, and backpressure. When I'm using Spring WebFlux with Project Reactor in a microservices world with Spring Cloud, do I still need resilience4j? Which features are provided by resilience4j that are not available in Project Reactor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has a few more features that are not baked in into Reactor, namely rate limiter, bulkhead and circuit breaker.

Comment: Actually bulkhead support is better with reactor than resilience4j. We have to use `subscribeOn/publishOn`.